# Update nested resource via parent controller & view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, error-handling, routes

How can I update a nested resource inside its parent's controller & view?

```
pry(main)> Duel.last #Duel has_many Duelers
 id: 16,
 consequence: "test",
 reward: "test",
 created_at: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 19:01:46 EDT -04:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 19:01:46 EDT -04:00>
pry(main)> Dueler.last
 id: 26,
 user_id: 78,
 challenge_id: 175,
 created_at: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 19:01:46 EDT -04:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 19:01:46 EDT -04:00,
 duel_id: 16,
 accept: nil>
pry(main)> Dueler.find(25)
 id: 25,
 user_id: 15,
 challenge_id: 192,
 created_at: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 19:01:46 EDT -04:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 19:01:46 EDT -04:00,
 duel_id: 16,
 accept: nil>
[15] pry(main)>
```

When a user clicks `submit` for `@dueler`, `@dueler` should then 1) update and 2) redirect back to duels/show.

**duels_controller.rb**

```
class DuelsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_duel, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  respond_to :html

  def show
    @dueler = Dueler.find_by(user_id: current_user.id)
    respond_with(@duel)
  end

  def create
    @duel = Duel.new(duel_params)
    @duel.save
    redirect_to duel_request_url(@duel)
  end

  private
    def set_duel
      @duel = Duel.find(params[:id])
    end

    def duel_params
      params.require(:duel).permit(:consequence, :reward, duelers_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :challenge_id, :accept])
    end
end
```

**duels/show**

```
<% @duel.duelers.each do |dueler| %>
    <%= dueler.user.name %> <%= dueler.user.last_name %> will <%= dueler.challenge.name %>
<% end %>

The loser(s) will <%= @duel.consequence %><br><br>
If everyone succeeds they will <%= @duel.reward %><br><br>

<%= form_for @dueler, :url => { :controller => "duels", :action => "show" }, :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
  Accept? <%= f.check_box :accept %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But instead upon `submit` I get the error: `Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/duels/13"`. In routes.rb there is `resources :duelers   resources :duels`

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your method to `patch`:

```
<%= form_for @dueler, :url => { :controller => "duels", :action => "show" }, :html => {:method => :patch} do |f| %>
```

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions), `resources` will create a `POST` route for creation. For updates `PATCH` method is used.